# Quelle est la difference entre les verbes « aller » et « se rendre (lieu) » ?

Tags: sens, usage, verbes

Dans quelles situations peut-on utiliser ces verbes ?

Y a-t-il une différence d'utilisation ou de sens ?

Exemples à commenter/différencier :

> **Je vais** à la bibliothèque.
>
> **Je me rends** à la bibliothèque.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Se rendre* à pour première signification :

> "Se soumettre, céder"

par exemple : "se rendre à l'évidence", ou "le forcené s'est rendu (s'est livré à la police)". 
Pas tout à fait dans le contexte de la question, il y a tout de même une notion de mouvement, un parcours abstrait de l'erreur vers la réalité, de la clandestinité vers la justice.

Le deuxième sens  :

> "Se transporter, aller"

indique qu'il faut utiliser un moyen de transport pour *se rendre quelque part*.
Il y a aussi une notion d'un *soi* qui se donne une destination, un but précis (personne sociale).

*Aller*, pour ce qui concerne la question :

> "Marque le déplacement d'un lieu dans un autre" et aussi "se déplacer".

Sans indication de moyen utilisé.
Le synonyme cité est "marcher", il y a donc une notion d'autonomie.
Il y déplacement d'une personne (personne physique).

L'usage n'est pas aussi simpliste car il est tout à fait possible d'entendre quelqu'un dire

```
Je me suis rendu à pied à la bibliothèque
J'irai en voiture à la bibliothèque
```

D'où un problème d'intention du narrateur :

En employant le sens premier, il semble plus judicieux d'ajouter le moyen de transport utilisé lorsque l'on utilise *se rendre* pour ne pas paraître d'un autre âge, voire prétentieux.

En ajoutant le moyen utilisé pour *aller*, on insiste sur la contrainte ou le problème rencontré pour exécuter ce déplacement.

*Définitions extraites du petit Robert.*

Answer (score 5):

En général, il n'y a qu'une différence de niveau de langage, *se rendre* est pour moi plus recherché qu'aller.

Je perçois aussi une légère nuance, *se rendre* est plus actif, et demande une participation au moins dans la décision.  Je ne dirais pas qu'un prisonnier se rend au tribunal quand on l'y emmène en fourgon cellulaire.

Comment: Pour le prisonnier je n'utiliserais pas non plus le verbe « aller », comme tu l'as dit on l'y emmène.

Comment: Il n'avait qu'à pas se rendre à la police!

Answer (score 4):

S'il y a une nuance de sens, elle est quasi imperceptible pour la plupart des francophones, me semble-t-il.

En revanche, il y a une différence de registre de langage, la variante **se rendre (à)** étant nettement plus formelle ou vieillissante. On la rencontre principalement à l'écrit, et elle est de plus en plus souvent remplacée par le plus générique **aller (à)**.