# Past participle "rendu" being used as an adjective, but not directly applying to a noun nor using a copula? ("rendue à" meaning "when I went to")

Tags: grammaire, participe-passé

I'm having trouble with the bolded sentence.
<sub>*(It came from a youtube [video](https://youtu.be/OACrq6bZpWs?t=177) with non-auto-generated subtitles. The unbolded sentences are there to give context).*</sub>

> La menace, c'était vraiment de contracter le virus, surtout près de ma
> date d'accouchement. **Donc j'avais peur de tester positive *rendue à
> l'hôpital*.** Puis là, j'entendais des histoires d'horreur de : tu vas
> être séparée de ton bébé ou tu vas être séparée de ton conjoint.

DeepL translates the bolded sentence with:

> So I was afraid to test positive when I went to the hospital.

Looking at [this](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/past-participle/) grammar webpage about the past participle, I see that the past participle can be used as an adjective. Here are two ways, shown on that webpage, that the past participle can be used as an adjective:

- Sometimes the past participle is applied to a noun; for example: "Il y a **une voiture *arrêtée*** au carrefour.". This seems to be a straightforward use of the past partciple.
- Sometimes the past participle is linked to a noun, through a copula verb; for example: "Les **enfants sont *assis*** dans le salon"

However, with the bolded sentence, "rendue à l'hôpital" doesn't seem to follow either pattern. I'm unsure what it is applying to (is it applying to "Je"?).

If I translate the sentence literally and directly into English, word-for-word, I observe that the translation is ungrammatical, and thus the French sentence uses a structure that clearly doesn't exist in English: "So, I was afraid to test positive **went to the hospital**". (I haven't seen this structure before, so I'd like to learn more about it.)

Questions:

1. My best guess is that this sentence might be an ellipses of "Donc, j'avais peur de tester positive **quand je suis** rendue à l'hôpital". Is this correct? (And if so, can you give other example sentences with past participles being used as adjectives, but where they don't seem straightforwardly linked to a noun, nor linked to a noun by using a copula?) If not, can you explain the structure of what "rendue" is applying to, and why it means "when I went"?
2. Would the following sentence have the same meaning, or not? "Donc j'avais peur de tester positive, **en rendant** à l'hôpital". If yes, why might the original sentence have been used instead of the more "common" present participle?

Comment: I think at one point in your question you wrote "present participles" instead of  "past participles". Not sure it was an involuntary typo or not  I did not want to correct your question.

Comment: @None thanks; you caught a typo! it was a typo under "Questions 1", but intentional under "Questions 2".

Comment: And this makes me realize we  haven't answered part 2, it might have seemed accessory to the rest. It should be *j'avais peur de tester positive, en **me** rendant à l'hôpital*, you can't miss out the **me** here (when going to the hospital, if I went to the hospital). And *en  me rendant à l'hopital* is not interchangeable with *une fois rendue à l'hopital*.

Comment: @None I might ask a separate question asking about "en me rendant", actually. I notice that I still am not 100% sure about what tenses are required (présent? passé composé? gerund?), and the differences in meaning when using different tenses, but there is probably enough to discuss about that in a separate question. My main confusion about the use of the past participle "rendue" has been answered, so I'll mark the question as answered!

Comment: I expect your tense problem is not special to *se rendre* it might be more general and lie in the way French and English (and maybe your mother tongue) use tenses, French has a lot more tenses than English and uses do not overlap.

Comment: Left you [a comment in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58708778#58708778)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1- In your example part of the sentence is omitted, which is quite possible and correct, you could read it this way:

> *Donc j'avais peur de tester positive *une fois que je serais rendue* à l'hôpital*.

It is the same type of sentence as in the example you found:

> *Il y a une voiture arrêtée au carrefour*.

in which the relative clause is ommitted (*Il y a une voiture (qui est) arrêtée au carrefour*).

*Être rendu* means *être arrivé*.

2-  *Se rendre* vs *être rendu*

*[Se rendre](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/french-english/se-rendre)* est synonyme d'aller.

- *Je me rends à l'hôpital*. (→ I go to the hospital).

(some people can see a difference in meaning between *se rendre* and *aller*, for more on that you can read the answer to this question: *[Quelle est la différence entre les verbes « aller » et « se rendre (lieu) » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6412/358)*

- *Je me suis rendue à l'hôpital*: (→ I went to the hospital).

So it means *aller* when the action expresses a movement. When we say *je suis rendue* (the verb is no longer pronominal) it does not express an action, but a state. *Aller* cannot be used in this case, *être rendu* is then synonym of *être arrivé*.

- *Je suis rendue à l'hôpital*. (→ I have arrived at the hospital).

I won't say the translation from DeepL is completely wrong when using *aller*, but it lacks nuances.<sup>1</sup>

3- It should be *j'avais peur de tester positive, en **me** rendant à l'hôpital*, you can't miss out the **me** here because it means *aller*.
And *en me rendant à l'hopital* (when going to the hospital) is not interchangeable with *une fois rendue à l'hopital* ("once I am/I was at the hospital").

<sup><sup>1</sup> "When I went to hospital" vs "once I arrived at the hospital".</sup>

Comment: 1) It's exciting that I'm advancing in my French Learning, as a beginner, enough that I'm ready to absorb the subtle difference between se rendre and rendre in this case! (I haven't come across this in a dictionary or grammar text, yet). 2) About une fois: is there a difference between "**une fois que** je serai rendue" and "**quand** je serai rendue"? (in English, "once I arrived" and "when I arrived" seem to have the same meaning). 3) Is it gramatically correct to instead use "*en rendant* à l'hôpital" (or "en arrivant à l'hôpital")? If so, am I correct to guess tht the meaning wd be dffrnt?

Comment: 3 continued) And that the difference in meaning would be "I worried **while I was arriving** at the hospital"? 4) It was *very* instructive to be shown that "une voiture arrêtée" is a contraction of "une voiture qui est arêtée". It makes "une fois renduee" in jlliagre's answer make more sense to me. (i've never seen "une fois" before). thanks.

Comment: @silph There is roughly the same difference between *quand* and *une fois que* as between "when" and "once", I would not use *quand* in your example because I think it important to show the immediacy of the action. You might also be interested by this: [Can “once” mean “when”?](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2016/01/once-when.html).

Comment: Ça se dit aussi chez toi, *Je suis rendue à l'hôpital* ?

Comment: @jlliagre Ça peut se dire, moi je l'emploie peu, je l'entendais plus il y a ...  disons quelques décennies en arrière, je pense que c'est en perte de vitesse, ce que confirme [ce ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rendu+%C3%A0+destination+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crendu%20%C3%A0%20destination%3B%2Cc0) - je lui ai mis un complément de lieu sinon on sait bien que les ngram ne sont pas significatifs.

Answer (score 3):

That's indeed an ellipsis but, as far as I'm used to, not of ***quand je suis*** because the tense wouldn't work, colliding with other meanings of *être rendu*. An less ambiguous alternative would be ***une fois***:

> *J'avais peur de tester positive **une fois** rendue à l'hopital.* (once [arrived] in the hospital).

It's more common to drop *[rendue](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rendu/1)* and just use *une fois*:

> *J'avais peur de tester positive **une fois à l'hopital**.*

Note that *quand je serai **rendue** à l'hôpital* seems to become either outdated or a regionalism in France for *quand je serai **arrivée** à l'hôpital*. The verb *rendre* requires a reflexive form in normative French (*quand je **me** serai **rendue** à l'hôpital*) but the meaning is slightly different (see comments).

***Tester positive*** is also a regionalism or an anglicism.

A more common expression in France is ***être testée positive***.

> J'avais peur d'être testée positive une fois à l'hôpital.

Comment: Il me semble que « quand je me serai rendu » et « quand je serai rendu » ne veulent pas dire la même chose (ce que je **crois** comprendre dans ton dernier §). « Quand je serai rendu » me semble couvrir un laps de temps plus grand, ça veut dire « une fois que je serai allé à/passé par l'hôpital » ( peut-être rentré chez moi, parti faire une autre course, l'action est terminée). « Quand je serai rendu » s'arrête à l'arrivée à l’hôpital,  la locutrice parle vraiment de l'arrivée à l'hôpital (le test est la première chose qu'on « subit » à l'arrivée à l'hôpital!).

Comment: @None Oui, je suis tout à fait d'accord avec ça. Je propose bien *être arrivée* comme signification d' *être rendue*. La dernière phrase a bien un sens légèrement différent. Elle ne me sert qu'à montrer un usage plus courant aujourd'hui du verbe (se) rendre.

Comment: @None I am reading your comment. in *« Quand je serai rendu » me semble couvrir un laps de temps plus grand*, did you mean instead "Quand je **me** serai rendu"? That is, "quand je me serai rendu" covers a longer period of time (eg the longer process of preparing to go to the hopital, driving on the road, and then arriving at the hospital), in contrast to "quand je serai rendu" meaning the shorter time period of actually arriving at the hospital?

Comment: @jlliagre Can you elaborate on why "quand je suis rendue" wouldn't work? I thought that "quand je suis rendue" is the passé composé of "rendre" (and would mean "when I arrived")? In contrast, I'm trying to understand "quand je serai rendue", which seems to be the future tense of *être*, acting as a copula that links "je" to the adjective "rendue" (meaning literally "when I will be arrived", or in more natural English, "when I will have arrived"). In English, we could say "I was worried when I arrived at the hospital", but not "I was worried when I will have arrived at the hospital".

Comment: @jlliagre (continued): Why is "quand je serai rendue" (a future tense) needed here, instead of "je suis rendue" (what I thought might be the passé composé)? **update**: damnit, I just looked up "rendre conjugation" and i see that the passé composé uses *avoir* as the auxillary verb, not être. But my question still applies: why is it "quand je serai rendue" instead of "quand j'ai rendue"?

Comment: *Rendre* has various meanings. To be honest, I never use *rendu(e)* that way, the reason why I wrote that I suspect a regionalism. A quick search shows a lot of occurrences a from Québec, and I remember hearing people from Eastern France saying that too. I If say *je suis rendu(e)*, I mean "I'm being returned to", like a product returned to its owner but that doesn't make sense for an hospital. You are right that if *rendue* means *arrivée*, the sentence *j'avais peur de tester positive quand je suis arrivée à l'hopital* works.

Comment: Another point:  I would rather have say *j'avais peur d'être testée positive* instead of *de tester positive*, sounds like an anglicism to me. I just had a look to the video, it confirms it's French Canadian.

Comment: @silph I did mean *quand je me serai rendu* (movement: once I've been to wherever...) vs *quand je serai rendu*  (position: once I have arrived at whatever place I want to be)

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of [*rendue*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rendue/1) is as in this entry from the TLFI:

> A.  Arrivé à destination. Le temps de se dire bonjour (...) et nous
> partons, de manière à être rendus, à 1 heure moins le quart (...) au
> passage Verdeau (VERLAINE, Corresp., t. 1, 1864, p. 14). Vous n'aviez
> qu'à prendre par la crête: vous étiez rendu en cinq minutes! (VERCEL,
> Cap. Conan, 1934, p. 162).

*Arrivée à l'hôpital* would have the same meaning: "once I got to the hospital."

Answer (score -4):

I think the correct, and simplest, response to this question has been lost by assuming that *rendu* in this instance concerns travel to or arriving at the hospital. *Rendre* has several translations into English, but surely the relevant one here is *give* or *render*. The translation of **Donc j'avais peur de tester positive *rendue à l'hôpital*** is then **So I was afraid of a positive test *being given at the hospital***.

Comment: This *Rendue* meaning would have been acceptable when, for example, used by a kidnapped girl returned to her parents (*[quand j'ai été] rendue à mes parents*) but it just can't work for a pregnant woman and an hospital unless that woman has been previously abducted from it, which clearly isn't the case here.

Comment: @jilliagre It's not the woman who is rendered, it's the test result. Is this not possible?

Comment: This kind of ellipsis would be awkward as the test itself isn't directly mentioned, that's the action (being tested). A way to adapt the sentence to that reasoning might be: *j'avais peur que des tests positifs me soient rendus à l'hôpital*.

Comment: *Qu'un test positif soit rendu à l'hôpital* (sans le *me*) est ambigu. Voici quelque chose d'idiomatique : *j'avais peur qu'un jugement défavorable soit rendu au tribunal*.

Comment: Or "... j'avais peur qu'un test positif soit rendu à l'hôpital". My apologies for my previous suggestion. I thought an infinitive ("tester") could be used as a noun in French, as it is in English. As a slight variation, surely "J'avais peur d'être testé positif rendu par l'hôpital" is correct?

Comment: Ah, I got it now. There are only a few cases where the infinitive can be used with an article in French, e.g.: *le manger* (see https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19121/why-are-de-quoi-and-du-manger-used-here)

Comment: *J'avais peur d'être testé positif rendu par l'hôpital* doesn't work.